# Reactive Cassandra Callback doInSession is not executed

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-data-cassandra

I follow one example with small modifications: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-webflux-first-steps

My ServiceImpl looks like:

```
private final HotelRepository hotelRepository;

private final HotelByLetterRepository hotelByLetterRepository;

public HotelServiceImpl(HotelRepository hotelRepository, HotelByLetterRepository hotelByLetterRepository) {
    this.hotelRepository = hotelRepository;
    this.hotelByLetterRepository = hotelByLetterRepository;
}

@Override
public Mono<Hotel> save(Hotel hotel) {
    if (hotel.getId() == null) {
        hotel.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    }
    Mono<Hotel> saved = hotelRepository.save(hotel);
    saved.then(hotelByLetterRepository.save(new HotelByLetter(hotel)));
    return saved;
}
```

After `Hotel` entity is saved logic try to save `HottelByLetter`.

In repository I inject `ReactiveCassandraOperations` and for a save method I just call insert method.

```
@Repository
public class CassandraHotelRepository implements HotelRepository {

    private final ReactiveCassandraOperations cassandraTemplate;

    public CassandraHotelRepository(ReactiveCassandraOperations cassandraTemplate) {
        this.cassandraTemplate = cassandraTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Hotel> save(Hotel hotel) {
        return cassandraTemplate.insert(hotel);
    }
}
```

After service call only `Hotel` is saved, `HotelByLetter` is not saved.
After debug I found that:

In `ReactiveCqlTemplate` method `createFlux` is called properly two times with correct `ReactiveSessionCallback`.

```
protected <T> Flux<T> createFlux(ReactiveSessionCallback<T> callback) {

    Assert.notNull(callback, "ReactiveStatementCallback must not be null");

    ReactiveSession session = getSession();

    return Flux.defer(() -> callback.doInSession(session));
}
```

But, `callback.doInSession(session)` is executed only once for insert new hotel.
I try also to extend `ReactiveCrudRepository`, but same issue.

I'm using: org.springframework.data/spring-data-cassandra/2.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR;

You need to work with the results of each publisher operator to apply the actual operation which created the `Publisher`.

### Explanation

Project Reactor's fundamental concept is to never mutate a `Publisher` through operators but rather returning a new instance. That's different in contrast to say a `Future` like `CompletableFuture` where you're able to register callbacks, and you're not obliged to reuse the result of the callback registration method to make it work.

The code of your `HotelServiceImpl` should look like the following:

```
class HotelServiceImpl implements HotelService {

    // …

    @Override
    public Mono<Hotel> save(Hotel hotel) {
        if (hotel.getId() == null) {
            hotel.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        }
        Mono<Hotel> saved = hotelRepository.save(hotel);
        return saved.then(hotelByLetterRepository.save(new HotelByLetter(hotel)));
    }
}
```

Calling `saved.then(…)` creates a new `Mono`. Dropping (not using) that `Mono` will result in not executing the `.then(…)` operator. Instead, returning the result of `saved.then(…)` will do also save `HotelByLetter`.